# DevExpress 11.1 not functional in IIS 7+

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have created a web application using Devexpress trial version. I have installed the trial version in my local machine. And I have created a application in IIS, in a new machine, and copied the web application from my machine to the new machine and configured the virtual directory. New machine has IIS 7 and OS is windows 7. I have copied the required dlls into 'bin' folder (new machine). In new machine application is working fine but the controls are not functional in ASPxGridView, when I try to add or edit records the application seems to freeze, when I click the command buttons the application stop to work

P.S.: In VS2010 when I run (debug) works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be an issue with the database (connection or command). The ASPxGridView uses callbacks for updates and other operation. If you clicked edit/update and it does nothing then there may be a problem reaching your backend. Try the approach mentioned in this video to catch the callback error:
http://tv.devexpress.com/#ASPxHttpHandlerModule

Comment: [SOLVED] Man, sorry was a bad address of my *.js file. thank you.

Comment: You tip was useful 'cause I re-check my solution.